# What kind of amperage and sticks needed to weld a nut to a stripped cap/bolt?

Tags: tools, stuck-bolt, welding

I was trying to get a cam gear cap/bolt thing off a 2000 Volvo S80 2.9l and stripped the torx pattern out of a bolt. I'd guess it's around 1-1/2" in diameter, and this is what it looks like:

[image: volvo cam gear cap]

I have tried other things like using JB Weld to hold a torx bit in and cutting a slot in the cap and trying to use a hammer and screwdriver to turn it but nothing has worked so far. Besides drilling it out, the only other thing I can think of is welding a nut to it (don't have enough room to fit a normal sized drill and bit in there anyway).

I've only ever tack welded for a job I had and they set everything up for me. I'm not sure what amperage or the kind of sticks I need. I definitely don't want to blow through the cap, or weld it to what's behind it. It needs a strong weld, because it doesn't want to come loose for some reason.

***What kind of amperage and sticks needed to weld a nut to a stripped cap/bolt?***

***Can someone provide me with some direction on how to get this done successfully?***

Comment: What kind of welder do you have available?  Here's a [reference.](http://www.weldingtipsandtricks.com/remove-a-broken-bolt.html)  If the part is still in the car, a Tungsten Inert Gas (TIG) welder is really best.  With that welder it's much easier to control the heat.  Is the part still in the car or is it on your workbench?  Frankly if the part is out of the car, this would be a very inexpensive repair at a local welder.

Comment: They don't have a left hand thread do they?

Comment: just to make sure the cam gear is metal? ive seen plastic cam gears before and they shatter under heat.

Comment: Engine and all still in the car. Double checked to make sure it wasn't left-handed. Cam gears are metal. I don't have welder right now; probably going to buy a used stick welder, since MIG and TIG are a bit more expensive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mig welder is what I use for welding nuts to broken fasteners, 100-120 amps or better should do it on that size bolt. Stick welder about the same amps, use a 6013 rod, 6011 for better penetration if needed.

My amp recommendations are general in nature, you want the most heat and penetration you can get quickly without melting the nut completely.